# Recover default Theme

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, themes, appearance

Accidentally, I deleted the /usr/share/themes folder... I reinstalled the light-theme and finally I got my theme back but with one issue: Around some buttons there is a white border: In nautilus https://i.stack.imgur.com/reNMl.png and in gedit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu7jG.png
For example the search button on the right side (in the pictures).

If I change the theme to numix or arc, these buttons are completely white... I already refreshed the icon cache, forced unity to reset and tried other themes. Nothing helped.

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I use `Oomox` to create custom themes.  you can fully customize and export themes.  You should be able to change all the colors to what you want.  If this doesn't work it sounds like you have some problems with `Unity Tweak Tool`.  Try reinstalling it.  Make sure you `purge` to remove config files.  Hope this helps.